# How can I query the reverse of has_many through?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, model, controller, associations

I'm trying to display a User's meetings with the following associations.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :panels
    has_many :meetings, through: :panels
end
```

```
class Meeting < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :panel
    has_many :users, through: :panels
end
```

```
class Panel < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :Meeting
  belongs_to :panel_head, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :panel_member_1, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :panel_member_2, class_name: "User"
end
```

I can show a Meeting's panel members with the following code:

```
@meeting.panel.panel_head
@meeting.panel.panel_member_1
@meeting.panel.panel_member_2
```

How do I go about doing the reverse? If I wanted to display a user's meetings I initially thought to try `@user.meetings` but that didn't work. I then tried `@user.panel.meetings` but I get thrown an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I ended up figuring out in case someone comes across this same problem...

In my User model I made the following query:

```
def meetings
    Meeting.joins(:panel).where("panels.panel_head_id = ? OR panels.panel_member_1_id = ? OR panels.panel_member_2_id = ?", id, id, id)
 end
```

I can now use `@user.meetings` and be returned with an ActiveRecord Association.